# grep NOT with regex

Tags: regex, ubuntu, grep

From a FASTA file I am trying to save the row that do not contains any of these characters: `A`, `C`, `G`, or `T` and lines that do not start with `>`. I thought that the regex `[^ACGT]` would have done the trick, but the output are blank lines

```
xx@LAPTOP-OP4UUVLH:~$ cat test.txt
>
TTTCCTTTCTGTGATTCCTCAAGCCCCATGGACTTACCGCTTTACCAACAACTGCAGCTAAGCCCGTCTT
CCCCAAAGACGGACCAATCCAGCAGCTTCTACTGCTAYCCATGCTCCCCTCCCTTCGCCGCCGCCGACGC

xx@LAPTOP-OP4UUVLH:~$ grep -v "^>" test.txt | grep "[^ACTG]"

xx@LAPTOP-OP4UUVLH:~$
```

Note that the last line of `test.txt` contains `Y` character and thus should be printed. Why it is not printing just the line with the Y ?

I am running ubuntu app in windows 10.

```
xx@LAPTOP-OP4UUVLH:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: you mean A,C,G,T four of them in any order lines should be removed?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the second line contain a character that is not A or C or G or T. Therefore, by using [^ACGT] I would have expected to have the whole second line returned.

Comment: That does seem odd. It looks like it should work (and does work on Fish shell in Mac OS).

Comment: I have tried on mac OS and now is working. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: just tried also with ubuntu 16.04 (in a virtual machine, not the windows app) and is working...I guess is an issue only for the windows app. any idea what might be the issue ?

Comment: Add a short part of your real file to make some tests.

Answer (score 0):

For the file (`test.txt`):

```
>
TTTCCTTTCTGTGATTCCTCAAGCCCCATGGACTTACCGCTTTACCAACAACTGCAGCTAAGCCCGTCTT
CCCCAAAGACGGACCAATCCAGCAGCTTCTACTGCTAYCCATGCTCCCCTCCCTTCGCCGCCGCCGACGC
```

the command you've provided (`grep -v "^>" test.txt | grep "[^ACTG]"`) prints:

```
CCCCAAAGACGGACCAATCCAGCAGCTTCTACTGCTAYCCATGCTCCCCTCCCTTCGCCGCCGCCGACGC
```

If you're getting empty output then check for trailing spaces.

Comment: can I grep -v the trailing spaces?

Comment: Sure, change first grep to:  `grep -v "^>\|\s" `

Comment: Try `cat -t test.txt` to check for tabs or non-printing characters.